# Не могу создать сессию

Tags: php, сессия

Имеется код который должен авторизировать пользователя. Авторизация держится на сессиях разумеется. Только когда код отрабатывается то сессии не создаются.

```
# авторизація
if (isset($_POST['user']) AND isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $id = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if (read_pass($pdo,$id,md5($pass)) == 'OK') {
        $key = md5(time().md5($pass.md5($id)));
        add_key($pdo,$id,$key);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['key'] = $key;
        echo "logined: ".$key;
    } else {
        echo "bad password!";
    }

# вихід
} elseif (isset($_POST['exit']) AND $_POST['exit'] == 'Вихід') {
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['key']);
    session_destroy();
    echo "exit";
}

#header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: а как вы определяете, что сессия не создается?

Comment: @teran Вот как `<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['key'])) {
   include_once "pages/office.php";
  } else {
   include_once "pages/auth.php";
  }
 ?>` постоянно подключает pages/auth.php

Comment: sission должна подключаться до любовго вывода в браузер. если соблюдать все правила, она не может не создаваться

Comment: как известно, `session_start` возвращает булево значение. Если думаете, что она не создается, то проверьте результат вызова функции. В противном случае проблема  не в создании а в дальнейшем использовании.

Comment: @Daniil переместил сессию в самый верх втраницы и проблема решилась, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

переместил сессию в самое начало страницы

```
<?php
   session_start();
   include_once 'functions.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

а код изменил на...

```
#авторизація
if (isset($_POST['user']) AND isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $id = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if (read_pass($pdo,$id,md5($pass)) == 'OK') {
        $key = md5(time().md5($pass.md5($id)));
        add_key($pdo,$id,$key);
        $_SESSION['key'] = $key;
        echo "logined: ".$key;
    } else {
        echo "bad password!";
    }

#вихід
} elseif (isset($_POST['exit']) AND $_POST['exit'] == 'Вихід') {
    unset($_SESSION['key']);
    session_destroy();
    echo "exit";
}

#header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

проблема исчезла и сессия начала создаватся